# keyof this in options argument

Tags: typescript

In a method type signature, the type `keyof this` can be used to constrain an argument to be the string name of a valid key of the class. It doesn't work, however, if the method takes options-style, as opposed to positional arguments. i.e:

```
class Foo {
  // Allowed
  m1(a: string, b: keyof this) {
    ...
  }

  // Error: A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface
  m2(options: {a: string, b: keyof this}) { 
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there any way around this? Thanks.

Comment: With `b: keyof Foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can extract `options` type and pass `this` as a generic parameter:

```
type Options<T> = { a: string, b: keyof T };

class Foo {
    m2(options: Options<this>) {}
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgCoD4oF4oBvKAQwC4o1gAnBFAcwBooAjSgawhCQDMosUAL4BuALAAoSQGMANqTRooAMSRJikqFqgBbAEwAKJPGTpKcRKkzAAFgjQ4AlMSGTXUiXIVLVSPVAgAD2AIFAATHzUNCW0yCigUAFcdVggaAigARnEJd0kUCAB3FTVDRwA6fQMSeIByWpZ2KAAiUlJm4UcgA)